# angularjs (1.2.0) not printing results to page

Tags: json, angularjs

I've got an angularjs view that I'm trying to print its results and even though the indexing and console output show the data I can't get it to show up in the actual page.

My console output of the json data received:

```
[Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]
0: Object
  $$hashKey: "004"
  _id: Object
    $oid: "527994c48776385b2e4a6e78"
  __proto__: Object
  author: "Undefined author"
  content: "Undefined content"
  title: "stfu"
  __proto__: Object
1: Object
  $$hashKey: "005"
  _id: Object
    $oid: "52799b0a8776385c490cd268"
    __proto__: Object
  author: "adam-stokes"
  content: "some content here"
  title: "dieeeee"
```

My controller code:

```
'use strict';                                                                                                                                                                                               

var cagewebControllers = angular.module('cagewebControllers', []);                                                                                                                                          

cagewebControllers.controller('IndexCtrl', ['$scope', '$http',                                                                                                                                              
    function($scope, $http) {                                                                                                                                                                               
        $http.get('http://localhost:9000/entity/page').                                                                                                                                                     
        success(function(data, status, headers, config) {                                                                                                                                                   
            $scope.pages = data;                                                                                                                                                                            
            console.log($scope.pages);                                                                                                                                                                      
        });                                                                                                                                                                                                 
    }                                                                                                                                                                                                       
]);
```

My app code:

```
'use strict';                                                                                                                                                                                               

var cageweb = angular.module('cageweb', [                                                                                                                                                                   
    'ngRoute',                                                                                                                                                                                              
    'cagewebControllers'                                                                                                                                                                                    
]);                                                                                                                                                                                                         

cageweb.config(['$routeProvider',                                                                                                                                                                           
  function($routeProvider) {                                                                                                                                                                                
      $routeProvider.                                                                                                                                                                                       
»         when('/', {                                                                                                                                                                                       
»             templateUrl: 'partials/index',                                                                                                                                                                
»             controller: 'IndexCtrl'                                                                                                                                                                       
»         }).                                                                                                                                                                                               
»         otherwise({                                                                                                                                                                                       
»             redirectTo: '/'                                                                                                                                                                               
»         });                                                                                                                                                                                               
  }]);
```

my template partial:

```
<h1>Pages</h1>                                                                                                                                                                                              
{{pages.length}}                                                                                                                                                                                            
<div ng-repeat="page in pages track by $id(page)">                                                                                                                                                          
  page {{$$hashKey}} - {{page.title}}                                                                                                                                                                       
</div>
```

my template layout:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>                                                                                                                                                                                             
<html ng-app="cageweb">                                                                                                                                                                                     
  <head>                                                                                                                                                                                                    
    <title>{{ title }}</title>                                                                                                                                                                              
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css' />                                                                                                                                                 
    <script src="javascripts/lib/jquery/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>                                                                                                                                     
    <script src="javascripts/lib/angular/angular.js"></script>                                                                                                                                              
    <script src="javascripts/lib/angular/angular-animate.min.js"></script>                                                                                                                                  
    <script src="javascripts/lib/angular/angular-resource.min.js"></script>                                                                                                                                 
    <script src="javascripts/lib/angular/angular-route.min.js"></script>                                                                                                                                    

    <script src="javascripts/app.js"></script>                                                                                                                                                              
    <script src="javascripts/controllers.js"></script>                                                                                                                                                      
  </head>                                                                                                                                                                                                   
  <body>                                                                                                                                                                                                    
    <h1>cage-webbbbb</h1>                                                                                                                                                                                   
    <div class="view-container">                                                                                                                                                                            
      <div ng-view class="view-frame"></div>                                                                                                                                                                
    </div>                                                                                                                                                                                                  

  </body>                                                                                                                                                                                                   
</html>
```

$scope.pages does contain the json data and I can see the data with console.log($scope.pages) but for whatever reason I can not get it to print on the page itself. im not sure if its something easy im missing but a second set of eyes would be much appreciated.

thanks

Comment: Is that HTML living inside `index.html`?

Comment: yea the template layout is my index.html

Comment: Aren't you missing a `.html` in the routeConfig? I mean: `when('/', {templateUrl: 'partials/index.html', controller: 'IndexCtrl'})`

Comment: @battlemidget do you have to use angular.js? you can do this easily via jQuery getJSON function

Comment: Try `templateUrl: 'partials/index.html',`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the comments I was able to narrow down my issue. I probably should've mentioned that the application server was nodejs with expressjs using hogan as the templating engine...and guess what, hogan uses the same syntax as angular for processing variables :\ once I switched to ejs I was able to print to the page.

thanks!